# How to connect properly android app to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an android app with the firebaseUI for the authentication.

I have downloaded the `google-services.json` and put it in my project but the login to firebase give me this problem.
[image: console error]

I'm working on this app with another guy but with his pc he doesn't have these problem. I also tryed to remove the app from the firebase console and download the `google-services.json` again but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using correct package name?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that